# Calculating Between Dates based on two dates

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Say the user specifies these two dates....
Start Date: 2010-12-05
End Date:   2011-01-15

If I select December 2010 I should get the folllowing
startdate = 2010-12-05
enddate = 2010-12-31

Select January 2011 then
startdate = 2011-01-01
enddate = 2011-01-15

Should I subtract dates? How can I get the start and enddate
for the current month/year based on the overall start and end date. I'm coding in vb.net

Comment: You need to be more specific. You don't actually ask a question which is answerable without making a number of large suppositions...

Comment: what do you want if you select FEB?

Comment: What rule dictates the start/end date? IOW, how could we know that the start date is `5 Dec` for the first example, and end date is `15 Jan` for the second example? Those are both purely arbitrary unless we have a rule to go by.

Comment: @slugster these dates are selected by user(another user)

Answer (score 1):

If my telepathy still works, it could be something like:

```
Dim startDate As Date = DateTimePicker1.Value
Dim endDate As Date = DateTimePicker2.Value
Dim selectedDate As Date = New DateTime(DateTimePicker3.Value.Year, DateTimePicker3.Value.Month, 1)

If selectedDate >= startDate AndAlso selectedDate <= endDate Then
    Dim resultStartDate = New DateTime(Math.Max(startDate.Ticks, selectedDate.Ticks))
    Dim resultEndDate = New DateTime(Math.Min(endDate.Ticks, selectedDate.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1).Ticks))
Else
    MsgBox("Outside of range")
End If
```